# Why doesn't my CSS border appear on a span around a button?

Tags: html, css

Using bootstrap 3.

I am trying to have a button inside a span and then apply some red border to the span. But somehow whatever I do the border does not appear.

Below is my code:

```
 <td>
    <span style="border-color:red">
        <button type="button" ng-click="dosomething()" name="values" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>        
    </span>
 </td>
```

Any pointers to fix this

Comment: Your border needs to have width, style and color. 
So you need to set border-width, border-style (required) and border-color.
or just define something like: border: 5px solid red;

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the what style and width the border need:

```
border: 2px solid red;
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

The default `border-style` is `none`, so if you don't define that, then it won't have a border no matter what colour you tell it to be.

```css
span {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <button type="button" 
          ng-click="dosomething()"
          name="values" 
          class="btn btn-primary">
    Select
  </button>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Just one thing, because both my button and span are inside my TD the span seems to be behind button. I want my span to enclose my button nicely and have some spacing between. See the image of what I have https://ibb.co/NsP4mV8

Answer (score 2):

this should do the trick.

```html
 <td>
    <span style="border: 2px solid red;">
        <button type="button" ng-click="dosomething()" name="values" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>        
    </span>
 </td>
```

if i were you i would add a border to the button because it looks nicer. that would look like this

```html
 <td>
    <span>
        <button style="border: 2px solid red;" type="button" ng-click="dosomething()" name="values" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>        
    </span>
 </td>
```

Comment: But then the border won't be on the span, but the button?

Comment: fixed it, now there is a border around the span.